# Right name for Python OpenCV video capture exposure setting

Tags: python, image, opencv, camera, video-capture

I know this is a useless question, but I couldn't find di answer anywhere, so I'm curious to find the answer.
I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 and Python 3.5.2 to capture some images with different exposure time with `cv2.VideoCapture`, like this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
k = -4
cap_next = cap.set(15, k)
ret, img = cap.read()
outcam = './img.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(outcam, img)
cap.release()
```

However, I managed to access to the exposure video attribute only through its number, and not with its name string: when I substitute `15` with `CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` or `CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` I get the error `NameError: name 'CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE' is not defined`.
Do you know how to do that with my current version of OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` or `cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE`?

In my OpenCV 3.1.0, Python 2.7 there is such value:

```
print cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE
15
```

Comment: so this mean by default .exposure setting is 15. Is it?

Comment: No. It means that exposure property has ID = 15. That's not the value of the exposure itself.

Comment: I did not understand. 
Purpose is to capture some images with different exposure time.
Where to set different exposure time?